# How to resize component in a specific state Adobe XD

Tags: popup, components, adobe, adobe-xd

I want to have this component's size to only encapsulate the info button not the whole area. Is there a way to have a component have different sizes depending on components state.

Right now when i hover over that entire green area it changes to hover state, i want it to only activate when the "i" is hovered

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the component state and go to the left menu you can hide layer you dont want

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but hopefully this helps someone. This same problem was driving me insane! But there is a simple solution:
Rather than using the default "Hover State" in the component create a "New State" which will function as your hover state and name it whatever you like and design the default and new states. Then, go to the Prototype tab, select the icon you want to trigger the hover animation, then add a new Interaction on the right panel. Set the Trigger to Hover, and the Destination to your new state. Works perfectly, and now you will only trigger the hover animation when hover over your icon rather than the entire component area.